# Place an image to the center of another image using PHP GD

Tags: php, image, gd

I need to place an image to the center of another image(both horizontally and vertically) with dimension 700*350. I'm trying with the following code. But I'm getting image as stretched.

```
@header("Content-Type: image/png");
$imageURL = "flower.jpg";

// create a transparent background image for placing the $imageURL image
$imageResource  = imagecreatetruecolor(700, 350);
imagesavealpha($imageResource, true);

$transparentColor  = imagecolorallocatealpha($imageResource, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($imageResource, 0, 0, $transparentColor);
$backgroundImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageURL);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageURL);
imagecopyresampled($imageResource, $backgroundImage, 350, 175, 0, 0, 700, 350, $width, $height);
imagepng($imageResource, "newimage.jpg");
```

This is not centering the image and also the file flower.jpg is getting deleted when I run this code. What I'm doing wrong in this?

Can anyone please help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "centered" ? having margin all around the image ? or having no left-right margin and only top-bottom margin ? Your current example will start to copy the image from the middle to the corner.

Comment: An example of expected output would be nice.

Comment: @Proger_Cbsk..Should have margin all around the image..The resulting image should be centered inside the transparent image both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need something like this?

```
@header("Content-Type: image/png");
$imageURL = "flower.jpg";

// create a transparent background image for placing the $imageURL image
$imageResource  = imagecreatetruecolor(700, 350);
imagesavealpha($imageResource, true);

$transparentColor  = imagecolorallocatealpha($imageResource, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($imageResource, 0, 0, $transparentColor);
$backgroundImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageURL);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageURL);

imagecopyresampled($imageResource, $backgroundImage, 175, 85, 0, 0, 350, 175, $width, $height);
imagepng($imageResource, "newimage.jpg");
imagedestroy($imageResource);
imagedestroy($backgroundImage);
```

[image]

You had specified the center of the destination image as the destination coordinates and the whole destination image size instead of needed dimentions of the center rectangle into which the source image would be resized.

Also you didn't do `imagedestroy`, which you totally should.