# php merge transparent png image to jpeg preventing the white background

Tags: php, image, merge, gd

I have successfully merged a png image to a jpeg background using the php GD library however I would like the png image to have a transparent background yet a white background is constantly displayed as shown below:

[image]

I have looked at a few posts to fix this issue and tried different methods of implementation all in vain, any suggestions as to what I should add or do?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $background = imagecreatefromjpeg('img3.jpg');
        $bird = imagecreatefrompng('img4.png');
        $bird_x = imagesx($bird);
        $bird_y = imagesy($bird);

        imagesavealpha($bird, true);
        $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($bird, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($bird, 0, 0, $color);
    if (imagecopymerge($background, $bird, 0, 0, 0, 0, $bird_x, $bird_y, 100))
        {
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            imagejpeg($background);
            imagedestroy($bird);
        }
        else
            {
                header('Content-Type: text/html');
                echo "Failed to Merge images!";
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: Add some code samples here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use imagecopy

```
imagecopy($dest_image, $src, ($offset + 250), $offset, 0, 0, imagesx($src),imagesy($src));
```

Comment: This is how I implemented the imagecopy `imagecopy($background, $bird, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($bird),imagesy($bird))` and it works however when I change the co ordinates of the bird a black box appears... suggestion as to how to prevent this?

Comment: @Murkdid may be the bird image is smaller than as per new coordinates

Answer (score 0):

I guess the specified behavior is by design.

`imagecopymerge` merges N% of pixels of the source image with (100-N)% of pixels from the destination image. From this definition it would be logical to assume that you won't see any of the background image pixels in the area where you've copied the bird (which is the full rectangle). Hence the white pixels instead of alpha.

Try `imagecopy` or `imagecopyresampled` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39897673/4725998)) without resizing.